# Is the CSR only required for requesting an SSL certificate or also for installing?

Tags: ssl

Does it mean you cannot migrate your SSL certificate is no longer possible? StartSSL offers free SSL certificates, but has a $25 for reissuing SSL certificates.

Is it important to make a back-up of the CSR in order to be able to migrate the SSL certificate later onto another server or is the CSR not required for installing an SSL certificate and only for requesting one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CSR is a Certificate Signing Request. The provider will sign this request and send you back a certificate file. You do not need hte CSR form this point onwards and can safely discard it.

When you come to renewing the certificate, you can generate a new request from your private key.

If you want to migrate the certificate to another server you can just take the existing one. So long as it is still valid (in date) and you're not changing your domain name (which needs to match the Common Name of the cert) then it doesn't matter how many servers it resides on.